# How to get logged in user in multiple websites OpenIdConnect Azure AD B2C?

Tags: asp.net-mvc, openid-connect, azure-ad-b2c

I want to use `OpenIdConnectAuthentication` for multiple projects. I'm using following code to authenticate user in my `website1` which is working fine but how can I access and manage that in `website2` same access token to authenticate user in another website?

```
public void ConfigureAuth(IAppBuilder app) {
// Required for Azure webapps, as by default they force TLS 1.2 and this project attempts 1.0
ServicePointManager.SecurityProtocol = SecurityProtocolType.Tls12;

app.SetDefaultSignInAsAuthenticationType(CookieAuthenticationDefaults.AuthenticationType);
app.UseCookieAuthentication(new CookieAuthenticationOptions());
app.UseOpenIdConnectAuthentication(
new OpenIdConnectAuthenticationOptions {
    // Generate the metadata address using the tenant and policy information
    MetadataAddress = String.Format(Globals.WellKnownMetadata, Globals.Tenant, Globals.DefaultPolicy),

    // These are standard OpenID Connect parameters, with values pulled from web.config
    ClientId = Globals.ClientId,
    RedirectUri = Globals.RedirectUri,
    PostLogoutRedirectUri = Globals.RedirectUri,
    AuthenticationType = Globals.DefaultPolicy,
    // Specify the callbacks for each type of notifications
    Notifications = new OpenIdConnectAuthenticationNotifications {
        RedirectToIdentityProvider = OnRedirectToIdentityProvider,
        AuthorizationCodeReceived = OnAuthorizationCodeReceived,
        AuthenticationFailed = OnAuthenticationFailed,
    },
    Scope = "openid",
    ResponseType = "id_token",
    // Specify the claim type that specifies the Name property.
    TokenValidationParameters = new TokenValidationParameters {
        NameClaimType = "name",
        SaveSigninToken = true,
        ValidateIssuer = false
    }//,

    // Specify the scope by appending all of the scopes requested into one string (separated by a blank space)
    //Scope = $"openid profile offline_access {Globals.ReadTasksScope} {Globals.WriteT//asksScope}"
});
```

**Note:** website 1 is MVC project and Website 2 is API project to authenticate api call. How can we manage that?

Comment: You should be able to use the access token that you receive after completing the openidconnect flow to call the api, provided that the application that retrieves the access token (MVC) has permissions access the API.

Comment: @borka Do you have any working example reference? It would be good if you provide roughly ideas. Also it'll work in localhost for testing?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I can see a couple of things you need to change in order to get this working. First thing, since this is a server application that you are using, you can use the `authorization code flow` or the `hybrid flow` to authenticate the user.

That can be achieved like this:

```
// for authorization code flow
ResponseType = "code",

// for hybrid flow
ResponseType = "code id_token"
```

Note, when using this two flows, you will need to provide the client secret as well.

Once the user is authenticated on the identity provider, it will get redirected back to your application with an authorization code that you can use to exchange it for access_token and refresh_token.

So, in the `OnRedirectToIdentityProvider` method

```
OnAuthorizationCodeReceived = async n =>
{
    // swap authorization code for an access token
    // i think for AAD B2C the endpoint for retreiving tokens is (not sure though you'll need to double check) 
    // https://<tenant-name>.b2clogin.com/<tenant-name>.onmicrosoft.com/<policy-name>/oauth2/v2.0/token
    var tokenClient = new TokenClient("http://localhost:5000/connect/token", Globals.ClientId, Globals.ClientSecret);
    var tokenResponse = await tokenClient.RequestAuthorizationCodeAsync(
                    n.Code, n.RedirectUri);

    // use access token to call the user info endpoint
    // also check what the userinfo endpoint URL is
    var userInfoClient = new UserInfoClient("http://localhost:5000/connect/userinfo");
    var userInfoResponse = await userInfoClient.GetAsync(tokenResponse.AccessToken);

    // create a new identity using the claims from the user info endpoint (including tokens)
    var id = new ClaimsIdentity(n.AuthenticationTicket.Identity.AuthenticationType);
    id.AddClaims(userInfoResponse.Claims);
    id.AddClaim(new Claim("access_token", tokenResponse.AccessToken));
    id.AddClaim(new Claim("id_token", n.ProtocolMessage.IdToken));

    n.AuthenticationTicket = new AuthenticationTicket(
                    new ClaimsIdentity(id.Claims, n.AuthenticationTicket.Identity.AuthenticationType),
                    n.AuthenticationTicket.Properties);
}
```

You can get all of the URLs that you need from the metadata endpoint.

Once you do all of this, the access token will be a part of the user claims, and it will be stored in the auth cookie.

Then, once you do all of that you can use the access_token to call the protected API, provided on your API you have `JwtBearerAuthentication` set up, by providing the access_token in the header of the request to said API.

The `TokenClient` class is part of a library called IdentityModel which makes it easier to communicate with openidconnect endpoints

Comment: Thank you, will check it and let you know. Also by that way can we also get the user details on other website?

Comment: Well the id_token stores the details about the user, and also the access_token can store details about the user if its set that way. I haven't worked with AAD so i can't tell you for sure. But once you get the access_token, you can go to [this](https://jwt.io/) site and paste the token there to inspect its contents

Comment: ok, much appreciated. will test it and let you know if any issues.